# Screen Goes Black in Metro Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

My application goes black when I switch from Landscape to Fill View and navigate from one page to another for first time. Later it works fine, but first time it goes black.
Even it goes black when I switch from Fill to Landscape View and navigate from one page to another for first time. Later it works fine, but first time it goes black.
My code is written in C# and XAML.
I am not changing anything when I switch from Landscape to Fill or vice-versa.
I change it only when the view changes from Snap to Fill/Landscape or vice-versa..

Comment: Are you using the RTM or Preview version of W8?  I had this problem in  the preview version but it stopped when I installed the RTM version

Comment: I am using the final RTM.. I figured out what the problem is but I can't figure out the solution. I found out that I can't resize a textbox(basically font size).. If I do that then only my screen is going black..

Comment: I am using the final RTM.. I figured out what the problem is but I can't figure out the solution. I found out that I can't resize a textbox(basically font size).. If I do that then only my screen is going black.. Any solution for this?? I need to resize some of textblock while switching between views..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Resizing existing content it may be easier to have a separate set of content that is hidden until the user moves to snapped mode.

Use the VisualStateGroups to hide/show the appropriate set of content for the given full-screen/snapped view.

So instead of resizing existing fields:

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="FullScreenLayout">...
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="SnappedScreenLayout">...
        </Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">  
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FullScreenLayout" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SnappedScreenLayout" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>     
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here were just hiding the full-screen layout when we're in snapped mode and displaying our snapped mode layout.  There is more Xaml but it's contained and allows you to provide a view-specific layout, which makes the Xaml cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: I get your point, but don't you think there should be some other solution to this? I mean I have to develop a complete UI seperately for Snap View..

Comment: I think this is what MS expect you to do and the project templates create a separate, hidden, ListView that is only shown in Snapped View.  Most apps will have completely different functionality and layouy in Snapped view (mine do).  This was the feedback I had from MS when participating in their early adopter sessions.